# Create file and add to a eclipse java project programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, file

What I have searched and trying to do is create and add files to a target project automatically from my program, any idea on how to do it? Because so far I can create files and change whatever is necessary but can't see a way to add those to my other project.

Comment: What do you mean by `add`? Do you mean copy a file into another directory?

Comment: *"Thanks for any help,

Jader"*  Don't include salutations or sigs. in questions, they are noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to write it to the java project directory.  If it looks like it didn't work, try pressing Right Click > Refresh on your java project in eclipse.